# 'Some rats lived at/in the school. To get rid of them, the headmaster called in a rat control service.'

Tags: grammar, prepositions, semantics

Can one use "at the school" instead of "in the school" in,

**Some rats lived at the school. To get rid of them, the headmaster called in a rat control service.**

Comment: Also ["In our house" vs "at our house"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496703/usage-of-in-our-house-vs-at-our-house/496737#496737)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with it, but it sounds odd. We normally speak of people as 'living at' an address.

It would be more usual to say *The school was infested with rats* or *There were rats [living] in the school.*

Comment: (Unless it was written from - or involving - the perspective of the rats, who might consider it their address.)

Comment: Yes. The suggested duplicates don't address the colligation 'living at [the end house, the vicarage, the hostel' ...]' being associated solely with human dwellers (and perhaps their pets).